# What is the best constant $C$ such that $\int^{1}_{0} \dfrac{f^2(x)}{x^2}dx\le C\int^{1}_{0} f'^2(x)dx$ for all $f\in C^1[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm hoping to find the smallest possible $C$ such that $\displaystyle{\int^{1}_{0}} \dfrac{f^2(x)}{x^2}{\rm d}x\le C\displaystyle{\int^{1}_{0}} f'^2(x){\rm d}x$ for every $f\in C^1[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$. Note that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}} \dfrac{f(x)}{x} = f'(0)$, so the integral on the left hand side is well-defined.

We have $C\le 4$: from integration by parts, for $\varepsilon>0$ we have
$$\int^{1}_{\varepsilon} \dfrac{f^2(x)}{x^2}{\rm d}x = -\int^{1}_{\varepsilon} f^2(x){\rm d}\dfrac{1}{x}=-\dfrac{f^2(x)}{x}\bigg|^1_\varepsilon + 2\int^{1}_{\varepsilon} \dfrac{f(x)f'(x)}{x}{\rm d}x,$$
letting $\varepsilon\to 0^+$ yields
$$\int^{1}_{0} \dfrac{f^2(x)}{x^2}{\rm d}x = 2\int^{1}_{0} \dfrac{f(x)f'(x)}{x}{\rm d}x-f^2(1)+f(0)f'(0)=2\int^{1}_{0} \dfrac{f(x)f'(x)}{x}{\rm d}x-f^2(1)\le 2\int^{1}_{0} \dfrac{f(x)f'(x)}{x}{\rm d}x.$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\left(\int^{1}_{0} \dfrac{f^2(x)}{x^2}{\rm d}x\right)^2\le 4\left(\int^{1}_{0} \dfrac{f(x)f'(x)}{x}{\rm d}x\right)^2\le 4\int^{1}_{0} \dfrac{f^2(x)}{x^2}{\rm d}x\int^{1}_{0} f'^2(x){\rm d}x.$$
From this we can see that $C=4$ will do.

But is $C=4$ achievable? This seems impossible. What I can do best is $C\ge 4\log 2=2.772...$: let $f(x) = 1-(1-x)^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, then
$$\int^{1}_{0} f'^2(x){\rm d}x = \dfrac{n^2}{2n-1}\sim \dfrac{1}{2}n(n\to\infty),$$
and
$$\int^{1}_{0} \dfrac{f^2(x)}{x^2}{\rm d}x = 2\int^{1}_{0} \dfrac{f(x)f'(x)}{x}{\rm d}x-f^2(1) = 2n\int^{1}_{0} \dfrac{(1-x)^{n-1}-(1-x)^{2n-1}}{x}{\rm d}x - 1.$$
Note that for $k>0$, $\displaystyle{\int^{1}_{0}} \dfrac{(1-x)^{k-1}-(1-x)^k}{x}{\rm d}x = \displaystyle{\int^{1}_{0}} (1-x)^{k-1}{\rm d}x=\dfrac{1}{k}$, so
$$\int^{1}_{0} \dfrac{f^2(x)}{x^2}{\rm d}x = 2n\left(\dfrac{1}{n}+\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{2n-1}\right)-1\sim 2\log 2\cdot n(n\to\infty).$$
This shows that $C\ge 4\log 2$.

Comment: @MartinR Edited.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2001778/42969, where sharpness of the factor $4$ is demonstrated in the answers – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint%5E%7B1%7D_%7B0%7D%20%5Cdfrac%7Bf%5E2(x)%7D%7Bx%5E2%7Ddx%5Cle%20C%5Cint%5E%7B1%7D_%7B0%7D%20f%27%5E2(x)dx%24)

Comment: @MartinR That's amazing, thanks! So I vote to close my question.